# Selecting everything but the numbers inside square brackets and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

Like the title says I am trying to create some regex that selects anything but the numbers inside the square brackets. For example:

`6483463456[1234]623235[456]783467546[789]67467467`

I would like to replace everything but the numbers inside the square brackets with nothing (only be left with the numbers in the brackets). I want this:

`[1234][456][789]`

Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

`[^\[.*\]]`

The code above finds the numbers individually, including the numbers inside the brackets.

`\[(.*?)\]`

The code above does nothing, but looks right.

Am I close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to pick up the numbers around the square brackets, then only capture the numbers in between the square brackets (along with the brackets) to get rid of the rest.

Additionally, to match only digits, you should use `\d` instead of `.`.

Find:

```
\d*(\[\d*?\])\d*
```

Replace all with:

```
\1
```

Comment: The first one almost works for me.

The problem is it is set out like this:

6483463456[1234]623235[456]783467546[789]67467467

And i want to keep everything inside the square brackets

Comment: What do you want the result to be? Do you want `1234456789` or `[1234][456][789]`?

Comment: Thankyou, but this doesn't seem to work for me. "Can't find text"

Comment: Perhaps you're using an older version of Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the form of the string never changes:

- No spaces anywhere
- All characters are numeric

Then you can use:

```
(\d*)\[(\d*)\](\d*)
```

This will capture all three groups, so you could replace the entire match with the second group (the numbers inside the brackets).

Comment: This code seems to capture it like this:

[1234]53636454534673[5678]

And it is highlighting to replace:

[1234]53636454534673

Comment: Using it on that would mean that group 1 would have no matches, group two would have `1234` and `5678`, while `53636454534673` would be captured in group 3.